# Emberjs: How to get to a route parameter passed in via url in controller

Tags: ember.js

Consider routes:

```
this.resource('things', {path: '/things/:id'}, function () {
  this.route('edit');
});
```

Inside controller of the `edit`, how do I access the `:id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `paramsFor` method in the route to get parent route parameters.
So in your case you can also use the `setupController` hook of the edit route,

```
setupController(controller,model){
 this._super(...arguments);
 let { id } = this.paramsFor(this.routeName);
 controller.set('thingsId',id);
}
```